# GAS Libraries and ScriptProperties: Way to save property to including script (not library)

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to outsource all of my code to a library, however I am using ScriptProperties to set and get persistent, global variables (like "mode" : "edit" or "data") for every spreadsheet that uses the code.

According to the specifications it is not possible to have a library write to the hosting scripts ScriptProperties: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#scoping

> Script Properties(**): The same instance is visible to all including scripts when created in the library.
>
> ** This means that library has its own instance of the resource/feature and that all scripts that use the library share and have access to that same instance.

So this makes it impossible to set globals for every spreadsheet using one single code library.

Is there a workaround or a solution to this shortcoming of Libraries in combination with ScriptProperties?

Thanks and all the best

Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or perhaps coded a little more elegantly, and more reusable...

Also included functions which are useful when a spreadsheet is used by more than one user, and they each need to have their own settings.

```
/**
 *Returns a script property from the library file to a calling script

 * @param {string} key The name of the scriptProperty property to return.
* @return {string} the string value of the key passed
 */

function getLibraryProperty(key) {
  return ScriptProperties.getProperty(key);
}

/**
 *Returns the appropriate library property for the calling spreadsheet.
 * @param {string} key The name of the scriptProperty property to return.
* @return {string} the string value for the key passed

 */

function getLibPropForSpreadsheet(key){
  return(ScriptProperties.getProperty(setkey_(key).fullKey));

}
/**
 *Returns the appropriate library property for the calling spreadsheet by user
 * @param {string} key The name of the scriptProperty property to return.
 * @return {Object.<string,string>} Object containing the key, full key, and value
 */
function getLibPropForSSUser(key){
  return(ScriptProperties.getProperty(setkey_(key).fullUserKey));
}
/**
 *Returns the appropriate library property for the calling spreadsheet.
 * @param {string} key The name of the scriptProperty property to return.
 * @return {Object.<string,string>} the string value of the key passed
 */
function setLibPropForSpreadsheet(key, keyValue)
{
  return(setLibProp_(key, setkey_(key).fullKey, keyValue));
}

function setLibPropForSSUser(key, keyValue)
{
    return(setLibProp_(key, setkey_(key).fullUserKey, keyValue));
}

function setLibProp_(key, fullKey, keyValue){
  ScriptProperties.setProperty(fullKey,keyValue)
  var theResult = new Object();
  theResult.value = keyValue;
  theResult.key = key;
  theResult.fullKey = fullKey;
  return(theResult);
} 

function setkey_(key){
var theCaller = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
 var theUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
 var fullUserKey = theCaller + '-' +theUser+ '-' + key;
 var fullKey = theCaller + '-' + key; 
  var theKeys = new Object();
  theKeys.fullUserKey = fullUserKey;
  theKeys.fullKey = fullKey;
  return(theKeys);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is a pass an instance of of the hosting ScriptProperties to the library, i.e. something like that

```
function test() {
  var props = ScriptProperties.getProperties();
  MyLib.func1(props);
}
```

**MyLib.gs**

```
function func1(props) {
  var mode = props["mode"];
  //  ...
}
```

If the hosting script handles multiple spreadsheets then is possible to use a spreadsheet id as a part of property key, for instance, there are two spreadsheets with ids `XYZ000` and `XYZ001`. The hosting script contains a coupe of properties

- `XYZ000.mode` = `normal`
- `XYZ001.mode` = `extended`

The hosting script takes an active spreadsheet id and passes it to the library methods together with properties.

A sophisticated solution is to have a settings class of a spreadsheet, to store in the hosting script properties a JSON string representation of the settings class for every handled spreadsheet, to load a spreadsheet settings from the properties using the spreadsheet id and pass the settings instance to the library. Here is a sample code.

```
function Settings(mode) {
  this.mode = mode;
};

function setDefaultSettings() {
  var ID0 = "XYZ000";
  var SettingID0 = new Settings("normal");
  ScriptProperties.setProperty(ID0, SettingID0);
}

function test() {
  var props = ScriptProperties.getProperty("XYZ000");
  MyLib.func1(props);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have tried to resolve this...

I store all properties in the library, then use a getter and setter function in the library to make it easy for the calling spreadsheet to access these values.

Uses the id of the calling spreadsheet to make a compound key for the property name. Function returns an object with the fullkey (compound), the "bare" key, and the value back to the caller (validation, error checking, etc.).

**library.gs**

The setter

```
function setLibPropForSpreadsheet(key, keyValue)
{
var theCaller = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var fullKey = theCaller + '-' + key;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty(fullKey, keyValue)
  var theResult = new Object();
  theResult.value = keyValue;
  theResult.key = key;
  theResult.fullKey = fullKey;
  return(theResult);
}
```

The getter

```
function getLibPropForSpreadsheet(key){
 var theCaller = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var fullKey = theCaller + '-' + key;
  return(ScriptProperties.getProperty(fullKey));
}
```

Then you can use those functions in your calling spreadsheet script thus:

**spreadsheet.gs**

```
function setIt() {
var test =  getData.setLibPropForSpreadsheet("thesetting", "the value")
    Logger.log(test)
}

function getIt(){
 Logger.log(getData.getLibPropForSpreadSheet("thesetting"))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is asking in 2020, there is so much easier to pass an instance of properties that you want to manage from the library. So,yo just do this in the **onOpen** method or just a method called **initialiceLib** that set the initial config for the library when load the script.

in library:

```
var scriptProperties_;
/**
* Assign local document instance of property to a variable
* @param {Properties} properties - Instance of local document properties
*/
function setScriptProperties(properties) {       
   scriptProperties_ = properties;
}

//in some random function
function someFunction() {
   var someProperty = scriptProperties_.getProperty("propertyKey");
}
```

in the local script:

```
function initialiceLib() {
   LibraryAlias.setScriptProperties(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties());
}
```

This example is about sharing local script properties with the library. You can change for document properties (User properties are already shared).

In case that you don't want to initiate any library config, and you just want to manage all the properties of the documents or other scripts in the library script properties, of course you can implement a function in the library to set properties with de document ID as prefix, for example, to make every key unique for every document.