# Google Apps Script - ScriptProperties from a Library

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a theoretical question - no sample attached.

1. I have 2 GAS projects: LibPrj and UserPrj.
2. LibPrj is a library for UserPrj.
3. UserPrj sends parameters to LibPrj which is saved to ScriptProperties.

Now since the original invoker is User, I expected the parameters to be saved to UserPrj/ScriptProperties. However, it is saved to LibPrj/ScriptProperties. Is this expected?

Comment: Provide relevant code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAS Libraries and ScriptProperties: Way to save property to including script (not library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686987/gas-libraries-and-scriptproperties-way-to-save-property-to-including-script-no)

Comment: Indeed. I had already changed the implementation to accept the callers ScriptProperties. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with libraries on GoogleAppsScript, requires to understand [resource-scoping](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#resource_scoping). Depending on the services you use, some services will be scoped to the library and some will use the calling-script scope.

**Example.** Let's say you have a project (A) to retrieve a list of email from a google sheet. And you use a library (B) that uses the MailApp service to send templated email. The scope of the MailApp service will be the one of your project (A), even if its called from within the library (B).

But, with the same example, if the library (B) is asked to save data using the ScriptProperties service, the scope will be the one of library (B).

You will find a list of services that have shared-scope and the ones that haven't [within the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#resource_scoping). This is a constraint on google-side that you can't override.